# Why does `row_to_json(...)` accept a sub-query?

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I recently encountered this example (via [a tutorial](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql) and [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564654/select-query-in-row-to-json-function)):

```
 SELECT row_to_json(x)
 FROM (SELECT id, title FROM my_table) x;
```

I'm confused about the use of `row_to_json(x)`. I thought it only accepted rows, but it seems to also accept a sub-query. I found this counter-intuitive.  According to the documentation, it accepts a record: `row_to_json(record [, pretty_bool])`. Other examples online use a `row()` constructor: `row_to_json(row(col1, col2))`. Does this mean a sub-query is the same as a `record` and a `row value/composite value`?

Comment: `x` is not a subquery. It's an alias to a subquery. You could also use: `SELECT row_to_json(my_table)
 FROM my_table ;`. Would that make more sense? Related question: [What type of rows does `SELECT my_table FROM my_table` return?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202168/what-type-of-rows-does-select-my-table-from-my-table-return)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks very much for pointing that out. It makes a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given next example:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, title text);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
(1, 'Title 1'),
(2, 'Title 2'),
(3, 'Title 3');
```

> Does this mean a sub-query is the same as a record and a row value/composite value?

Let me select some records from `tbl`:

```
SELECT id, title FROM tbl;

id | title  
-: | :------
 1 | Title 1
 2 | Title 2
 3 | Title 3
```

Now using a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, title FROM tbl) t;

id | title  
-: | :------
 1 | Title 1
 2 | Title 2
 3 | Title 3
```

As you can see both queries return same rows, then you can use both queries to generate a JSON result.

> ```
> SELECT row_to_json(x) 
> FROM   (SELECT id, title FROM tbl) x;
> ```
>
> ```
> | row_to_json                |
> | :------------------------- |
> | {"id":1,"title":"Title 1"} |
> | {"id":2,"title":"Title 2"} |
> | {"id":3,"title":"Title 3"} |
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=de706cf0c28df448792004b3ebfa14b4)*</kbd>

As @ypercube has pointed out, when you executes:

```
SELECT tbl FROM tbl;
```

you get this result:

> ```
> | tbl           |
> | :------------ |
> | (1,"Title 1") |
> | (2,"Title 2") |
> | (3,"Title 3") |
> ```

same output as using:

```
SELECT ROW(1, 'Title 1');
```

> ```
> | row           |
> | :------------ |
> | (1,"Title 1") |
> ```

It is a (named) [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). (Have a look at docs about [TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html))

> By default, the value created by a ROW expression is of an anonymous record type. If necessary, it can be cast to a named composite type — either the row type of a table, or a composite type created with CREATE TYPE AS

Having a look at [row_to_json()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) function:

```
+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| row_to_json(record [,  | Returns the row as a JSON object.                  | row_to_json(row(1,'foo')) | {"f1":1,"f2":"foo"} |
|          pretty_bool]) | Line feeds will be added between level-1 elements  |                           |                     |
|                        | if pretty_bool is true.                            |                           |                     |
+------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

Uses a row as example: `row_to_json(row(1,'foo'))`

Comment: Besides `SELECT id, title FROM tbl;`, you could also show the output of `SELECT tbl FROM tbl;`. (and see my comment in the question and the linked one)

Comment: @McNets Thanks for taking the time out and explaining. It was very clear and removed a lot of my misconceptions.