# What type of rows does `SELECT my_table FROM my_table` return?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, composite-types

I sometimes encounter this `SELECT` statement (in JSON-related answers on stackexchanges):

```
SELECT my_table
FROM my_table;
```

It seems to turn a one-column result, with multiple rows.

What would be the name of the type of each row returned? A `row value of my_table`?

(I tried reading the documentation ([sql-expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html)) but, I could not find a specific answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a named composite type: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS

When you create a table, a [TYPE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) with the same name is created.

A row of that table is of that type.